# is_subcategory(); function for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

hi 
i know there are many nice functions in wordpress like `is_page()`, `is_single()`, `is_category();`...

do u know how i can create a `is_subcategory()` function?

thanks a million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There is not a `is_subcategory()` function but you can get the children (sub category) of a category and use as a conditional statement.

```
<?php
global $ancestor;
$childcats = get_categories('child_of=' . $cat . '&hide_empty=1');
foreach ($childcats as $childcat) {
  if (cat_is_ancestor_of($ancestor, $childcat->cat_ID) == false){
   //do stuff
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: nice one man... i got it to work nicely..  thank you for taking your time to do this.